# How likely would /var/mail be encrypted in a paid host?

Tags: email, privacy, web-hosting

I pay for a very basic web hosting plan, which includes a personal email address. Would the sysadmin of said host be able to read the content of my messages? How likely would my personal mail folder be encrypted and secure from prying eyes nowadays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By paying the company to host your website it means you have trusted them with full control on your website. 
Even if the websites directory was encrypted what stops the sysadmin from looking into the database and getting the key?

If you for some reason don't trust hosting company you can always host it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely that /var/mail is *not* encrypted. But ask the host and you know for sure.

Yes the sysadmin would be able to view and read your messages (encrypted or not, but if encrypted it's an extra barrier and depending on how the host has organized things a random sysadmin may or may not have access to the keys).